# How to implement a "one time login" in Android using Phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, jquery, cordova

I am developing a mobile application using PhoneGap for android and ios, I want to implement a login scheme like gmail and facebook applications i.e. the user has to enter a username and password only for the first time,after that the application should automatically log them in as soon as the it starts. I am calling web services through ajax and jquery which validates the login credentials.

I have seen many posts for ios that describe how to modify delegate.m file but what about android then?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the user session data in a persistent form of storage.Check if a user has logged in using this data.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

So the steps will be:

1.Check if a user has logged in using the data stored in local storage.You can either store the session id or a boolean say isLoggedIn.

2.If session id is null or isLoggedIn boolean false ,present the login form to the user.

3.Otherwise show the Home screen.

Make sure to delete data on user log out .

Answer (score 1):

U can Use Local Shared Preferences in JS.

If its null then forward to Login Page else Home Page.

init Code:

```
//function to  check if user is already logged in or not on Specific Screen
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#idOfthePage",function(event){
    var u_name=localStorage.getItem("PMUsername");
    var u_pwd=localStorage.getItem("PMPassword");

if(u_name==""||u_name==null ||u_name=="null" || u_name=="undefined" ||
u_pwd==""||u_pwd==null ||u_pwd=="null" || u_pwd=="undefined"
){
$.mobile.changePage("login.html");
}
else
{
$.mobile.changePage("home.html");
}
    });
```

To set The value in Local Storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("PMUsername","some_value");
localStorage.setItem("PMPassword","some_value");
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to put this line:              $(document).on("pageinit", "#load_splash",function(event)                 in Phonegap project?

Comment: its an pageinit method which will be called when user open your splash.html page.here, #load_splash is the id of a splash html page .

Comment: Thanks geet but can you tell me exactly where to put this code in the file that extends droidgap?

Comment: Put this code in your Js. Change `"#load_splash"` with your Page id. You can see the Html Part in my Edit answer.So function will be load at the initialization of your specific page.& Set Value of user name & password when user enter the value & save it.

Comment: Thanks Geet,I understood what you are trying to say but my question is where to put the code to load splash page in Phonegap? Also please tell me what is the validity of this storage i.e. for how much time it will be stored in the storage?

Comment: In your js file. Or you can put it in <script type="text/javascript">....init code...</script> of Html Page.

Comment: I think Geet you are somewhere wrong. Code to load the splash screen is done like this: extends DroidGap@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.ysnlogo);
  
        
        
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        //super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")z
         }  @Override
  public void init(CordovaWebView webView,
  super.init(webView, webViewClient, webChromeClien
t);

Comment: Please Read your question..You even dont know about that init code.splash screen is one of the example. Use this code on your way with your page, html or js.Your question is about to How to implement one time login in android using Phonegap? & its answer is by local storage . I have given you an example which you can use it.

Comment: Geet I am just asking you to tell me how to load splash html page in Phonegap?

Comment: Local storage will store the value untill you uninstall your app.M still not getting you that what you mean by "how to load splash html page in Phonegap".. be clarify or post another question regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Store username, password when you are first logging in,

```
window.localStorage["username_rem"] = 'username';
window.localStorage["password_rem"] = 'password';
```

For Remember add this code on your login page load event OR login event

```
if(window.localStorage["username"] != undefined && window.localStorage["password"] != undefined) 
{
  if(window.localStorage["username"] != "" && window.localStorage["password"] != ""){                   
    $('#frm_login :input[id=Usernamel]').val(window.localStorage["username"]);
    $('#frm_login :input[id=Password]').val(window.localStorage["password"]);                   
  }              
}
```